# Django-admin clean_fields override, keeps previous data on submit

Tags: django, validation, django-admin, django-forms

My question is quiet simple, I have a class in my app model that inherits from `models.Model`.

I'm overriding the `clean_fields` method of the django-admin, in order to execute some custom validation to my form. 
The problem is that when it raises a `ValidationError` from my custom validation, if the user tries to submit the form again with the correct information, it always keeps the data from the previous submit.

```py
class SignedOffModelValidation(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def clean_fields(self, exclude = None):
        super(SignedOffModelValidation, self).clean_fields(exclude)

        errors = {}
        if getattr(self, self._meta.immutable_sign_off_field, False):
            relation_fields = [
                f for f in self._meta.fields
                if isinstance(f,(models.ForeignKey,models.ManyToManyField,))
                and not f.name.endswith('_ptr')
            ]

            for field in relation_fields:
                try:
                    field_value = getattr(self, field.name)
                    signed_off = getattr(
                        field_value,
                        field_value._meta.immutable_sign_off_field
                    )
                except (AttributeError, ObjectDoesNotExist,):
                    continue
                else:
                    if not signed_off:
                        msg = u'In order to signeoff, %s needs to be Signed Off' % \
                            (str(field_value),)
                        errors[field.name] = ([msg])
            if errors:
                raise ValidationError(errors)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Best Regards

Comment: I have a hunch that your problem is associated with the view/form that is manipulating this model. Any chance you can post that?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `clean()` method rather than `clean_fields()`. This is pretty clear in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean%20Django%20Doc.).